# How to read the file when that file was changed?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I don't know how to use the watchdog script and read file script together.

```
import sys 
import time 
import logging from watchdog.observers 
import Observer from watchdog.events 
import LoggingEventHandler

if name == "main": 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    path = "C:/watch"

    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler() 
    observer = Observer() 
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True) 
    observer.start() 
    try: 
        while True: 
            time.sleep(1) 
    finally: 
        observer.stop() 
        observer.join()

    file = open('test.txt','r') 
    f = file.readlines()

    newList = [] 
    for line in f: 
        newList.append(line[:-1])

    print(newList)
```

Comment: I've added some newlines and indents; please double check that these indents are all correct, and that I have not accidentally changed your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are incorrect (syntax error), and so is the `if name == "main":` test, take another look at the example in https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/. Here's a patched version, plus a couple of changes listed below:

```
import sys 
import time 
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

def on_modified(event_handler):
    print(f'event_handler.src_path={event_handler.src_path}')

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    path = "C:/watch"

    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler() 
    event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    observer = Observer() 
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True) 
    observer.start() 
    try: 
        while True: 
            time.sleep(1) 
    finally: 
        observer.stop() 
        observer.join()
```

I added a callback function `on_modified` (currently does just a print), assigned it to your event handler's on_modified function, removed the editing of the "test.txt" file at the end. You should now put this into the callback function.

You can see in the callback function that `event_handler.src_path` is the path to a file that was modified: at that point, you can put the code to read the file.